# Add Vuetify 2 to vite project

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vite

My team developed application in Vue 2 with class based components and typescript.

Now, we want to migrate to Vite - because of all the advantages it carries.

I have followed this guide (which I can only recommend)
https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/

In short - it don't work. Browser can't even fetch "/src/main.js" from index.html
But if I put "/src/main.ts" it fetches it, but shows errors which indicates Vuetify is not even installed.
I know .ts files are not readable by browser, I just tried it after 2 hours of debugging

Also, I saw in Vuetify documentation that "First party Vite support" is still to be released.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/#in-development

My question is - **is it even possible to add Vuetify in Vite** **application**?

package.json (dependencies only)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.6.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.5.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vite": "^2.6.13",
    "vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.9.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "vite/client"
    ],
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { createVuePlugin as vue } from "vite-plugin-vue2";
const path = require("path");

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});
```

empty html rendered in the top, and "no vuetify" error indicator
when I put .ts import in index.html

```
<script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. But I'm getting 'Vuetify is not properly initialized'. The plugin (@vuetify/vite-plugin) appears only to be for Vue3 and dependency vuetify@"^3.0.0-alpha.11" dependency. Don't want to waste time migrating if I can't use stable Vuetify.

Answer (score 23):

There is support for Vuetify 2 [link](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#importing-from-ui-libraries)

first install the plugin

```
npm i unplugin-vue-components -D
```

Then in your vite.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { createVuePlugin } from 'vite-plugin-vue2'
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    createVuePlugin(/* options */),
    Components({
      resolvers: [
        // Vuetify
        VuetifyResolver(),
      ],
    }),
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Intall [unplugin-vue-components](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components).

```
npm install -D unplugin-vue-components
```

then add the plugin in `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue2 from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

defineComponent({
  plugins: [
     vue2(),
     Components({
        resolvers: [VuetifyResolver()],
     })
  ]
})
```

If you also use vuetify [custom sass variable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)

```
defineComponent({
  plugins: [
    vue2(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [VuetifyResolver()],
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: [
          // vuetify variable overrides
          '@import "@/styles/variables.scss"',
          '',
        ].join('\n'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

You can refer to my starter template with Vite 3 + Vuetify 2 + Vue 2.7
It also includes TypeScript support and intellisense in Vuetify 2 components

https://github.com/kingyue737/vitify-admin

Answer (score 2):

I've created startar template.

https://github.com/logue/vite-vue2-vuetify-ts-starter

Originally made for projects using `vue-property-decorator`, it also supports composition api.

If you want to access the vuetify function with the composition api, you can access it with `useVuetify()`.

Comment: This works out of the box. But it appears that options api not fully supported. I am having trouble with computed.

Answer (score 1):

I created repo where I migrate default `vue2`/`vuetify2` official template from **vue-cli** to **vite 5**.

It used mainly :

- `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` and `vue:^2.7.0` (this is minimal version required) for **vue 2**
- `unplugin-vue-components` for **vuetify 2**

See : https://github.com/sbernard31/vuetify2-vite-template